# Green bar on top of every (web) video, distorted colors too

Tags: windows-7, firefox, video, flash

Since a few days I have a problem with some videos I watch on the web (youtube, vimeo etc). There is a green bar on the top of the video and the colors are distorted, it looks like they are somehow shifted.

I am not sure since when this problem appeared, I guess it might have been an update for the flash player. Anyways, I found a workaround. Disabling the hardware acceleration, by unchecking `right click on video - settings - enable hardware acceleration`, helps. After reloading of the page the green bar is gone.

The problem is that this setting doesn't seem to be persistent and I have to disable it again on every other video. Next thing is that I prefer to use HW acceleration. How can I make this setting permanent or how to get rid of the green bar alltogether?

Comment: Do you use any cleaner tht deletes the settings you set? In that case you should check the cleaner to tell it to don't delete that setting.

Comment: I actually do, this probably caused the reset. Now that I have found the real cause of the problem I stick with my solution. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Updating the drivers for my graphic card solved the problem.

I feel a bit stupid, this probably would've been the first thing I had asked for in a comment if someone else had a similar question.

Answer (score 2):

You should try to uninstall and install again.

"uninstall flash player 32bit.exe" search this on google then, after you uninstalled completely, you proceed to reinstall it.

Comment: Agree it might fix it for good. I had a full green screen on specific flash sites, youtube being one of them. Disabling hardware acceleration did workaround the problem. But for some odd reason, a full retract of the install (using a image backup) and reinstallation of flash from the downloadable install , it has not had that problem again, or anywhere and hardware accleration is working too. The weird thing being that I just repeated the same process, and got different results.

Comment: Tried uninstalling flash plugin, and reinstalling it to latest version. That did not help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem on my HP Elitebook 8540w, which seems to occur after running CCleaner so it must have been deleting something it shouldn't but I have no idea what.

Tried but didn't work: 
- Uninstalling NVidia driver, restarting, installing driver via the device manager properties window automatically.
- Installing original NVidia driver downloaded from HP drivers site. v276.21.
- Downloading the latest Adobe Flash Player plug-in, uninstall and reinstall.

Solution:
- Installing latest driver from NVidia site for my graphics card (quadro fx 1800m). v296.35

Answer (score 0):

On my computer (Lenovo T420 /w Windows 7 64-bit Pro version), this problem occures with Firefox, but not with Chrome. I haven't even tried IE.

In my case, I have updated flash player, Firefox and display drivers, but no change. So I suspect the problem is related to Google's own video player - it is most likely having some compatibility issues with Firefox.

Comment: Not necessarily. Firefox, Google Chrome, and Internet Explorer **do not** share Flash Player. Each browser uses a different version/build of Flash Player. As a matter of fact, Google Chrome's Flash Player is built-in to the browser.