# Unable to watch some videos on YouTube

Tags: browser, codec, video-playback

When I try to watch some videos on YouTube, I get the output of the following type:
[image]

The behavior persists regardless of the web browser. Is there a solution for this problem?

Comment: Which version of Adobe Flash Player do you have installed? Are you using YouTube's HTML5 video player? Are your graphics drivers up-to-date?

Comment: Also, if you are using Flash, try disabling [hardware acceleration](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/help01.html).

Comment: maybe related: http://superuser.com/questions/409451/green-bar-on-top-of-every-web-video-distorted-colors-too

Comment: @iglvzx, version is 11.2.202.something. No. Yes.

Comment: @iglvzx, disabling hardware acceleration worked. Thank you! Can you please post it as answer so that I can upvote it and mark as correct?

Comment: Have you tried updating your graphics driver (as I recommend in my question/answer)? This could actually fix the problem and is not just a workaround.

Comment: What I meant is, have you downloaded the driver through the chip vendors (eg Nvidia, AMD) support or through some third party tool, like most laptops have one? In my case lenovo didn't offer the lastest driver, I had to checkout the latest off NVidia myself.

Comment: @WalterMaier-Murdnelch, I am also using Lenovo. I have not downloaded drivers, and I don't know if the drivers installed on my laptop are up-to-date.

Comment: @WalterMaier-Murdnelch, your suggestion is also appreciated. Could you please post it as an answer?

Comment: @missingfaktor I sometimes get this after a recent update to either my graphics card driver or Adobe Flash. I will just restart the computer and the problem will be gone. There was no need to disable hardware acceleration (which you must have enabled to ensure full use of your graphics card by Flash). Restarting the computer is a recommended "first-aid" when solving computer problems =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the issue is with Adobe Flash Player (as opposed to YouTube's [HTML 5 video player](http://www.youtube.com/html5)), disabling [hardware acceleration](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/help01.html) should fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem seems like a more extreme version of [the problem I had before](https://superuser.com/questions/409451/green-bar-on-top-of-every-web-video-distorted-colors-too).

As you said in your comments, you own a lenovo laptop, too. I assume you normaly update your drivers using the lenovo update tool. These drivers are mostly stable, but often not really up to date. I remember some time ago nVidia actually asked users to download the drivers for mobile solution from the laptop vendors site instead of their site. Whatever, this doesn't seem to be the case anymore, at least I have not found anything like that on their site.

So go to nvidia, download the latest drivers for your graphics card and install them. This should rid you off these green bars, somehow these seem to appear when using an older driver combined with the recent version of flash. Seems that the old drivers did not completely adopt some encoding standard.